# AngularJS ngSanitize says "lowercase is not a function"

Tags: lowercase, ngsanitize

My problem: I have to use the ngSanitize module, but when I run the project, I have the following error:

> Failed to instantiate module ngSanitize due to:
> lowercase is not a function.

I've had organized all my .js files, and organize all file versions, but the problem persists. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: have you included angular-sanitizer js on the page ?

Comment: Yes I did it...

Comment: which version of angular and sanitizer are you using? can you share code snippets of html with script includes and module initializer code?

Comment: can you replicate in http://jsbin.com/?html,js,output , even that should be fine.

Comment: Hi, I'd found the error, for a unknown reason my sbt was importing the angular in 1.7.0 version, in this angular version the angular.lowercase was removed.

Glad you guys are helpful and friendly!

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Had the same problem. Found out that my npm install failed somewhere in between. Just ran the command again and everything works fine! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd found the error, for a unknown reason my sbt was importing the angular in 1.7.0 version, in this angular version the angular.lowercase was removed. Glad you guys are helpful and friendly! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, npm was installing random version of ng-sanitize, so I removed ^(caret) sign from package.json for all the dependencies then run npm install, It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Update to latest version of angular and angular-sanitize.
Key is to install same versions of both libraries. If there is mismatch it might cause compatibility issues like lowercase or uppercase methods not found.