# AngularJS ngSanitize Error on 1.7.0

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, lowercase, versions, angular-sanitizer

I've got pretty much this error: 
[AngularJS ngSanitize Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213977/angularjs-ngsanitize-error)

short version: "lowercase is not a function".

While my application has AngularJS enforced to 1.4.9, we didn't enforce angular-sanitize, so it resolves to 1.7.0 and on that version of AngularJS lowercase function doesn't exist anymore, producing an error.

Probably by forcing angular-sanitize to a fixed version would fix that, but I want to go beyond fixing it and understand what is causing the problem and why, because I find a few inconsistencies.

- AngularJS is forced to 1.4.9. bower-components folder holds this version, build folder after compiling also holds this version, developer panel on Chrome show only this version is fetched. This version does have lowercase method.
- Angular-sanitize has angular 1.7.0 as a dependency, but it's never downloaded, never. Not in any single folder or subfolder on the entire project, not at compiling, not from Chrome either. So I guess the only *angular.js* he's got access to is 1.4.9, which does have lowercase method.

I don't quite understand why then "lowercase is not a function" error appears if the only available *angular.js* still has that method. Also I don't understand why angular-sanitize 1.7.0 demanding angular 1.7.0 uses non-existing methods on AngularJS 1.7.0 (Angular developers mistake? but I find hard to believe it.)

Probably sanitize is downloading and accessing angular 1.7.0 somehow, but I would like to know how. Just out of curiosity. And also to confirm if this is an angular developers mistake or if there's something I've missed.

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in the official [Angular 1.6 to 1.7 Migration Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-6-to-1-7):

> Due to [1daa4f](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/1daa4f2231a89ee88345689f001805ffffa9e7de), the helper functions `angular.lowercase` and `angular.uppercase` have been removed.
>
> These functions have been deprecated since 1.5.0. They are internally used, but should not be exposed as they contain special locale handling (for Turkish) to maintain internal consistency regardless of user-set locale.
>
> Developers should generally use the built-ins `toLowerCase` and `toUpperCase` or `toLocaleLowerCase` and `toLocaleUpperCase` for special cases.
>
> Further, we generally discourage using the angular.x helpers in application code.